How to get top and bottom height from an element from its position in scrollable div or modal


function calcHeight() {
  let myDiv = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  console.log('myDiv','scroll height = ',myDiv.scrollHeight, 'client height = ',myDiv.clientHeight, 'scroll top = ', myDiv.scrollTop, 'offset top = ',myDiv.offsetTop, 'offset height = ',myDiv.offsetHeight);
}
#myDIV {
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#content {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: coral;
}
.test {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
<div id="myDIV">
  <div id="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras velit augue, efficitur non tempus vitae, vulputate a sem. Curabitur mattis, justo sed vestibulum dictum, lorem sapien pulvinar nulla, at faucibus enim dui vel ligula. Phasellus vel leo non est varius pellentesque. Vestibulum ac pharetra magna, in posuere velit. Donec vel eros et metus facilisis consequat. Praesent augue tortor, pellentesque eget luctus at, ornare ut ligula. In nec massa ipsum. Fusce vitae leo commodo, tempus tellus eget, vestibulum diam. Etiam quis risus in odio pulvinar semper non vitae diam. Curabitur vestibulum mauris vitae tortor interdum, a iaculis est vestibulum. Aenean sed eleifend metus. Donec lorem dui, porta quis enim et, maximus auctor ex. Nullam a elementum diam. Suspendisse suscipit lorem vitae gravida porttitor.
    <div class="test">Test</div>
Donec dictum lectus id turpis pharetra dictum. Cras pellentesque ornare ex, eget interdum lorem vulputate id. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam pellentesque nulla vitae massa porttitor, nec fermentum mi tempor. Phasellus ac purus eros. Maecenas ac nisi accumsan, pharetra nisl at, sollicitudin enim. Cras convallis in mauris ac ultrices. Maecenas porta condimentum tellus, cursus lobortis urna varius non. Curabitur at massa vitae ligula fermentum congue at sed ipsum. Aliquam porta, magna vel ullamcorper sagittis, leo ante gravida augue, in aliquam lectus enim vitae velit. Nunc mattis consectetur eros at tristique. Donec ligula tortor, vehicula nec sapien quis, iaculis pharetra lacus.
In auctor est tortor, ullamcorper suscipit sem hendrerit nec. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris id dignissim justo. Duis finibus nisi risus, consequat lacinia elit eleifend sit amet. Proin accumsan, odio vel pharetra tempus, quam nisl condimentum lectus, a posuere magna orci ac nunc. Integer semper ante at lacus commodo placerat. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="calcHeight()">Get Height of test element</button>



enter image description hereI have an element with text test which is not absolute position in scrollable div and I need to calculate top height and bottom height from it's position as shown in screenshot?
How to get top and bottom height from an element from its position in scrollable div or modal

enter image description here

How you do this would depend on what your HTML and CSS looks like for that element. Please add it to the question, along with the JS you wrote so that we can help you to debug it

HI @RoryMcCrossan pls click the link (enter image description here) to see the code structure

An image is not helpful - even less so when that image crops out half of the JS code. Please copy+paste it as text in to the question

I have added the sample code, pls check @RoryMcCrossan

From the image provided, to get the h1 and h2 you can use this:
function calcHeight() {

let myDiv=document.getElementById("myDIV");
let testDiv=document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0];

var h1=testDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top - myDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top;
var h2=myDiv.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - testDiv.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

console.log(`'h1 = '${h1}, 'h2 = '${h2}`);
}

